# How to generate coverage report for http based integration tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, coverage.py

I am writing integration tests for a project in which I am making HTTP calls and testing whether they were successful or not.

Since I am not importing any module and not calling functions directly coverage.py report for this is 0%.

I want to know how can I generate coverage report for such integration HTTP request tests?

Answer (score 10):

The recipe is pretty much this:

1. Ensure the backend starts in code coverage mode
2. Run the tests
3. Ensure the backend coverage is written to file
4. Read the coverage from file and append it to test run coverage

Example:

#### backend

Imagine you have a dummy backend server that responds with a "Hello World" page on GET requests:

```
# backend.py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class DummyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'.encode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8000), DummyHandler).serve_forever()
```

#### test

A simple test that makes an HTTP request and verifies the response contains "Hello World":

```
# tests/test_server.py
import requests


def test_GET():
    resp = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    assert 'Hello World' in resp.text
```

#### Recipe

```
# tests/conftest.py
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time
import coverage.data
import pytest



@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def run_backend(cov):
    # 1.
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['COVERAGE_FILE'] = '.coverage.backend'
    serverproc = subprocess.Popen(['coverage', 'run', 'backend.py'], env=env,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    time.sleep(3)
    yield  # 2.
    # 3.
    serverproc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    time.sleep(1)
    # 4.
    backendcov = coverage.data.CoverageData()
    with open('.coverage.backend') as fp:
        backendcov.read_fileobj(fp)
    cov.data.update(backendcov)
```

`cov` is the fixture provided by `pytest-cov` ([docs](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markers-fixtures.html#cov)).

Running the test adds the coverage of `backend.py` to the overall coverage, although only `tests` selected:

```
$ pytest --cov=tests --cov-report term -vs
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- 
/data/gentoo64/usr/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /data/gentoo64/home/u0_a82/projects/stackoverflow/so-50689940, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.6.3, cov-2.5.1
collected 1 item

tests/test_server.py::test_GET PASSED

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.6.5-final-0 -----------
Name                   Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------
backend.py                12      0   100%
tests/conftest.py         18      0   100%
tests/test_server.py       5      0   100%
------------------------------------------
TOTAL                     35      0   100%


============================ 1 passed in 5.09 seconds =============================
```

Comment: I am getting an error with above coverage overwriting method. The .coverage is being overwritten when pytest is run. I am getting this error `coverage.misc.CoverageException: Doesn't seem to be a coverage.py data file`

Comment: This is probably due to conflicting versions of `coverage` package in `pytest` and on backend side, [related issue](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/408/coverageexception-doesnt-seem-to-be-a).

Comment: With recent changes in I think coverage 5.4 I think the last four lines should instead read

    backendcov = coverage.data.CoverageData(basename='.coverage.backend')
    backendcov.read()
    cov.get_data().update(backendcov)

Answer (score 2):

With Coverage 5.1, based on the ["Measuring sub-processes" section of the coverage.py docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.1/subprocess.html#measuring-sub-processes), you can set the `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` env-var, call the `coverage.process_startup()` somewhere in your code. If you set `parallel=True` in your `.coveragerc`

1. Somewhere in your process, call this code:

   ```py
   import coverage
   coverage.process_startup()
   ```

   This can be done in `sitecustomize.py` globally, but in my case it was easy to add this to my application's `__init__.py`, where I added:

   ```py
   import os
   if 'COVERAGE_PROCESS_START' in os.environ:
       import coverage
       coverage.process_startup()
   ```

   Just to be safe, I added an additional check to this `if` statement (checking if `MYAPP_COVERAGE_SUBPROCESS` is also set)
2. In your test case, set the `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` to the path to your `.coveragerc` file (or an empty string if don't need this config), for example:

   ```py
   import os
   import subprocess

   env = os.environ.copy()
   env['COVERAGE_PROCESS_START'] = '.coveragerc'

   cmd = [sys.executable, 'run_my_app.py']

   p  = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env)
   p.communicate()
   assert p.returncode == 0 # ..etc
   ```
3. Finally, you create `.coveragerc` containing:

   ```
   [run]
   parallel = True
   source = myapp # Which module to collect coverage for
   ```

   This ensures the .coverage files created by each process go to a unique file, which pytest-cov appears to merge automatically (or can be done manually with `coverage combine`). It also describes which modules to collect data for (the `--cov=myapp` arg doesn't get passed to child processes)
4. To run your tests, just invoke `pytest --cov=`