# How can pytest-cov report coverage of python code that is executed as a result of pexpect.spawn?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pexpect, pytest-cov

I have a Python project that uses pytest-cov for unit testing and code coverage measurement.

The directory structure for my project is:

```
rift-python
+- rift                        # The package under test
|  +- __init__.py
|  +- __main__.py
|  +- cli_listen_handler.py
|  +- cli_session_handler.py
|  +- table.py
|  +- ...lots more...
+- tests                       # The tests 
|  +- test_table.py
|  +- test_sys_2n_l0_l1.py
|  +- ...more...
+- README.md
+- .travis.yml
+- ...
```

I use Travis to run `pytest --cov=rift tests` for every checkin, and I use codecov to view the code coverage results.

The package under test offer a command line interface (CLI) which reads commands from stdin and produces output on stdout. It is started as `python rift`.

The tests directory contains two types of tests.

The first type of tests is traditional unit tests that test an individual class. For example, the test test_table.py imports table.py, and performs traditional pytest tests (using assert etc.) Code coverage measurement works as expected for these tests: codecov accurately reports which lines in the rift package are or are not covered by the test.

```
# test_table.py (codecov works)

import table

def test_simple_table():
    tab = table.Table()
    tab.add_row(['Animal', 'Legs'])
    tab.add_rows([['Ant', 6]])
    ...
    tab_str = tab.to_string()
    assert (tab_str == "+--------+------+\n"
                       "| Animal | Legs |\n"
                       "+--------+------+\n"
                       "| Ant    | 6    |\n"
                       "+--------+------+\n"
                       ...
                       "+--------+------+\n")
```

The second type of test uses pexpect: it uses `pexpect.spawn("python rift")` to start the rift package. It then uses `pexpect.sendline` to inject commands into the CLI (stdin) and it used `pexpect.expect` to check the output of the commands on the CLI (stdout). The test functionality is working fine, but codecov is not reporting the code coverage for these tests.

```
# test_sys_2n_l0_l1.py (codecov does not pick up coverage of rift package)
# Greatly simplified example

import pexpect

def test_basic():
    rift = pexpect.spawn("python rift")
    rift.sendline("cli command")
    rift.expect("expected output")  # Throws exception if expected output not seen
```

QUESTION: How can I get code coverage measurements to report the covered line in the spawned rift package for the 2nd type of test using pexpect?

Note: I omitted several what I believe to be non-relevant details, full source code at https://github.com/brunorijsman/rift-python (UPDATE: this repo now contains the working solution suggested in the answer)

Comment: Check out [the answer I gave to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50700912/2650249) (measure code coverage of a server spawned by an external command). There is a working example of a fixture that updates coverage measured by `pytest-cov`, must be pretty much the same of what you want.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for the pointer. This is useful, and I might need it if my scenario gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coverage run` to run your pexpect program and gather data:

If you usually do:

```
pexpect.spawn("python rift")
```

Then instead do:

```
pexpect.spawn("coverage run rift.py")
```

([Source](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start))

After testing you will likely want to combine the pexpect results with the "regular" unit test results.  `coverage.py` can combine multiple files into one for reporting.

Once you have created a number of these files, you can copy them all to a single directory, and use the `combine` command to combine them into one `.coverage` data file:

```
$ coverage combine
```

([Source](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html?highlight=combine#combining-data-files))

Two additional details from testing:

- In the test program (test_sys_2n_l0_l1.py) in this example, you must make sure that you have a delay between the moment that you terminate the pexpect spawn and the moment you terminate the test itself. Otherwise, coverage will not have time to write the results to .coverage. I added a sleep(1.0).
- Used "coverage run --parallel-mode rift". This was needed to (a) make sure .coverage was not overwritten by later runs and (b) make "coverage combine" work (which is automatically run by "pytest --cov")

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to enable [subprocess coverage tracking](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html).

I recommend using https://pypi.org/project/coverage_enable_subprocess/ to enable this easily.

Using `parallel = 1` is recommended/required then, and you have to export `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START`, e.g. `export COVERAGE_PROCESS_START="$PWD/.coveragerc"`.