# How can I measure code coverage of API integration tests?

Tags: python, django, api, pytest, code-coverage

In my company we have a Django project that has API endpoints.
We are using Pytest as testing framework and some of our tests executing requests to such endpoints using `requests.Session()`. For example:

The test perform a GET request to `/api/account/data`

##### content of root/dir/tests/test_api.py

```
def test_some_api(self):      
   client = requests.Session()    
   response = client.get('/api/account/data')
   assert response.status_code == 200
```

When performing the request, the backend execute this function:
`

##### root/models/account/api.py

```
def user_data(request, format=None):
    """
    @api {get} /api/account/data
    """
    if request.method == "GET":
        return APIResponse(code=200)
```

We would like to measure the code executed in `user_settings` by the test, but I failed to make it work. We are using:

`coverage==4.5.4`    # forced to use an old version as we have dependencies conflict

`pytest-cov==2.10.1`

To measure coverage I run this command from root

`pytest -v --cov-report html:html-report --cov=dir --cov-config=dir/.coveragerc`

.coveragerc - has only files to exclude

---

I verified in backend logs that when the test runs, it execute the `if` block inside `user_settings`

I have tried adding this code to `conftest.py` as written in coverage docs, but it still didn't measure `user_settings` code execution.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True) 
def run_cov():     
    process = coverage.process_startup()     
    source_path = os.path.join(_home_path, "/models/account")     
    cov = coverage.Coverage(config_file='root/.coveragerc', source=[source_path])     
    cov.start()     
    yield cov    # Tests runs here 
    cov.stop()     
    cov.save()     
    cov.html_report(directory='html-report')
```

I've seen this solution [How to generate coverage report for http based integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689940/how-to-generate-coverage-report-for-http-based-integration-tests), but failed to understand how to implement it on my end.

I expected `user_settings` code to be measured by `coverage` report.

Comment: Code coverage is a useful metric if the subject of your tests is code, like in unit tests. If the subject of your tests is an API, it gets less useful. What you should focus on instead is how much of the API is covered in the integration tests.

Comment: Are you starting a whole http server during your tests run in a separate process?

Comment: The server not being started during the tests, it is already up and running.